# How to give user selected text, formatting options as in Gmail android app?

Tags: android

How to provide the text formatting options above the keyboard(like Bold, Italics, Striked) for user selected text, entered by the user in my activity's `EditText` area , as shown in the below picture?

[Image Linked Here, Screenshot of Gmail app - Compose Email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwBH2.png)

I have searched a lot but not able to find the solution.
I also even do not know what is the perfect technical term used for this.

Thanks a lot in advance.